# db2 identity with hibernate configuration (SQL Error: -142, SQLState: 42612)

Tags: hibernate, db2, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

Please help on DB2 identity in Hibernate annotation.

Im using DB2 version 10.01, trying to insert values into the table using hibernate save() method.

Id annotation:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "stmciss_id",unique=true,nullable=false)
protected int id;
```

Hibernate configuration:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</property>
```

Identity creation in the schema:

```
"STMCISS_ID" INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (

            START WITH 5000000

            INCREMENT BY 1

            MINVALUE 1208950

            MAXVALUE 2147483647

            NO CYCLE

            NO CACHE

            NO ORDER ),

        "SER_NO" CHAR(6) FOR SBCS DATA NOT NULL,
        "TS" TIMESTAMP WITH DEFAULT NULL,
        "TS_DEF" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL WITH DEFAULT ,


    )
```

Getting the error as mentioned below:

```
Hibernate: insert into schema.table_name (id, cmplt_by_txt, cmplt_by_date, ts_last_updt, ts_load, ent_by_id) values (default, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Hibernate: values identity_val_local()
May 12, 2015 3:21:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: -142, SQLState: 42612
May 12, 2015 3:21:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-142, SQLSTATE=42612, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.15.113
May 12, 2015 3:21:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: -516, SQLState: 26501
May 12, 2015 3:21:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-516, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.15.113
May 12, 2015 3:21:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: -514, SQLState: 26501
May 12, 2015 3:21:07 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=SQL_CURLH200C1, DRIVER=4.15.113
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Answer (score 2):

it worked fine after dialect changed from `org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.DB2390Dialect.`

The above change working.

After the above transcation done. Next transcation onwords getting the below error:

Now im geeting the below error:

```
[2015-05-13 10:21:01,110] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
[2015-05-13 10:21:01,110] ERROR com.service.SerialServices - org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
[2015-05-13 10:21:01,110] ERROR com.SelectAction - org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1885)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)

    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:274)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:760)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:247)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:480)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:995)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:480)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:995)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.invoke(StandardContext.java:2416)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorDispatcherValve.invoke(ErrorDispatcherValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:577)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:480)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:995)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline$StandardPipelineValveContext.invokeNext(StandardPipeline.java:643)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:480)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:995)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:223)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:601)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11Protocol.java:392)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:619)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:736)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:114)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1134)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    ... 67 more
```